# Rails best practice for creating a resource on a relational model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to know what would be the best way to create / destroy a relational resource. For Eg.: I have two models called `Picture` and `Favorite`. A user can add a picture to his favorites.

```
class Picture 

end


class Favorite

 belongs_to :picture
 belongs_to :user

end
```

I would like to know which is the best place(practice) to add login in order to add a picture to his / her favorites. Is it better to add it in the `PicturesController` with a `favorite` action that would `create` or `delete` the favorite based on its existence, or else create a separate controller called `FavoritesController` and add two actions called `create` and `destroy`?

Answer (score 1):

The best approach following both **Rails conventions and RESTful principles** would be to create a **controller per resource**, containing the actions necessary to manipulate that resource. Based on your situation, you have a Favorite resource that can be both created and destroyed, so the route mapping should be something like this:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI      Pattern                  Controller#Action
  favorites     POST     /favorites(.:format)     favorites#create
  favorite      DELETE   /favorites/:id(.:format) favorites#destroy
```

And your controller should look like this:

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # Create a favorite here based on its params !
  end

  def destroy
    # Destroy a favorite here based on its id !
  end
end
```

About the login process, I really think it should be a concern of your `UsersController`, though some Ruby devs prefer to use `SessionsController`, since it is a [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) default.

Notice that you have the option to create nested resource routes which is a good idea when mapping `has_one` / `belongs_to` relations into routes, and it is indeed a best practice. You can check [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for details.

I'm not suggesting this kind of approach here, because when it comes to the `User` resource, it is not a good idea to have its id on your routes, and it is kind of a default to work with it in the backend.

I hope it helps :P

Comment: But as you know for the `create` action of favorites, it would need `picture_id`. Is it best to pass this in the `POST` request payload or rather with a route like: `/pictures/1/favorite`. The latter would definitely mean to create two routes in the picture controller like `add_favorite` and `remove_favorite`. But my question is this against he `Separation of Concerns` in `rails`?

Comment: If you must have picture_id (and indeed you must), you should definitely follow the nested resource route approach that I recommended in my response.